# Make Public Report Default

Tags: oracle-apex

Using Apex version 4.1.1.00.23.

When saving a report and choosing Actions, Save Report, the resulting window has a "Public" check box to make the report Public.  Is it possible to have the Public check box already checked ( resulting in Public being the default option)?

I read that it is not possible to have the option to only have Public reports without also having Private reports.  Is this true?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to have public reports without the private ones simply because of the way saving is set up. If you were to influence that, then yes, it would be possible.

You can not easily influence the 'Public' checkbox. The reason for this is that the html-region which pops up when you select an option from the actions list (such as 'save' in this case) is retrieved through an ajax call. This way it is not even possible to use some javascript/jquery to influence this as the item is not there as long as the option has not been selected.

If you really want to influence it anyway, there is one option only: study the ajax calls and reproduce them. For example, i've been doing this for filters. You will need to look through the ir javascript file, found in `/i/javascript/apex_interactive_reports_4_1.js`

Firstly, you need need a hook for the successful callback for the IR ajax. There are however no framework events. What i did is 'override' `gReport._Finished_Loading`: checking the executed action, trigger the original code, then hook in my own functions.
Once there, you could influence what happens: hide the checkbox, always check it, add items or change some. For example, with always checking the checkbox and hiding it you'd always generate public reports.

You could also study the save report ajax call, and mimic this behaviour, using your own small interface for providing parameters.